# I got confused with the following Kotlin Statement

Tags: kotlin, nullable

```
val s = person.name ?: return
```

I know that the `?` is used for null safety... but what does `:return` do.

Answer (score 8):

`?:` is called [Elvis Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator).

```
val s = person.name ?: return
```

equals to:

```
val s = if (person.name != null) person.name else return
```

which means if `person.name` is `null` then return.

Comment: thanks a lot... it's more expressive and descriptive

Answer (score 2):

[`?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) returns the expression on its right side in case the expression to its left is `null`.

In this case, instead of giving `s` a value, it will just return from the current function immediately. You can also throw an exception in a similar manner, in case something is `null` and you have no good way to proceed with what you were going to do with it.

This example is basically shorthand for the following (assuming name is a `String?`):

```
val s: String? = person.name
if(s == null) {
    return 
}
// you can use `s` here as it will be smart cast to `String`
```